# pandas df: extracting data with numeric column name in excel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to extract data from excel file year-wise using pandas, the excel file is in this form:

```
File-a          
         2000     2001   2002
01/01    0.50     6.7    4.66
01/02    1.55     5.5    5.8
01/03    2.36     4.4    7.8
```

I am doing something like this:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('file_path')
sheets= xl.sheet_names
table2 = xl.parse(sheets[0], header=0)

df_append=table2.ix[1:,1:2]

arr=df_append.values.tolist()
arr=np.squeeze(np.asarray(arr))
price_arr=np.array2string(arr,separator=', ')
print price_arr
```

I need to convert the data in column 2000, 2001 etc in array and extract those dynamically using column name, and not like the column index I have done above. I tried doing this but it didnt work:

```
 df_append=table2.ix[1:,'2000']
```

Can you please suggest how can I extract data according to the particular year column?Also, the year column starts from the second row, its not in the header column. Thanks.

Comment: What is the final output you are expecting ?

Comment: [0.5,1.55, 2 .36] if i extract for year 2000.

Comment: Please post `table2.head().reset_index().to_dict('list')` so that we can understand exactly what DataFrame you are working with.

Comment: This is just the dummy table I have created of the original one, but the original is something like this: {u'File-a': [nan, u'1/1 00:00 - 01:00', u'1/1 01:00 - 02:00', u'1/1 02:00 - 03:00', u'1/1 03:00 - 04:00'], 'index': [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L], 2015: [nan, 0.5, 1.55, 2 .36, 0.64]}